# iMac target display mode with Macbook air running Ubuntu

Tags: windows, macos, ubuntu, thunderbolt

I've bought a thunderbolt cable and I'm trying to get TDM working between my iMac and Macbook Air. It works if both devices are booted into OSX however when I boot my Macbook Air into Ubuntu, it no longer works.

Does anyone know of a work around for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain it is supported by the OS, not just the hardware.

You can't even do it in Boot Camp, so I very much doubt you will find any support for it in Ubuntu.
Sorry.